# How can I show that $AΔB = A^c Δ B^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is a question from a quiz given from my teacher, have anyone managed to solve it?

$$AΔB = A^c Δ B^c$$

I have tried proving by saying $AΔB= A\setminus B \cup  B\setminus A$ or $= A∪B \setminus (B \setminus A)$ and then i rewrite this formula with the: complementary $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Aside from the typesetting issues: what is the problem? Is it to prove that? To disprove it? And what have you tried?

Comment: You've made some strange choices in asking you question.  First of all, the title of your question should say what the question is about, not how difficult you find the question to me.  Second, how did you choose these tags?  What do calculus and group theory have to do with this?  Third, it's not totally clear what you're asking, but I think the question asks you to show that
$$
A \Delta B = A^c \Delta B^c
$$
is that what you mean?

Comment: Finally, and this is an important point: when you ask questions on this site, you're expected to include some of your own thoughts on the question. Yes, you've said that it's difficult, but what did you try?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Usually, you'll want to put dollar signs around anything that's math. For example, `$AΔB$` shows up as $AΔB$.

Comment: To add to the other comment, typing `$A \Delta B$` also produces $A \Delta B$, but doesn't require copy/pasting the triangle.

Comment: @NguyễnBảoHưng great, it would be best if you would edit your question to include this.

Comment: Thank you omnomnomnom, i will try to edit this now. Btw, do you know how to write the symbol for "union" and "intersection" ?

Comment: @NguyễnBảoHưng `$A \cup B$` becomes $A \cup B$.

Comment: @NguyễnBảoHưng Glad to Help. Also, be sure to look at the answer that was posted.  If it answers your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the $\checkmark$.  If you're still confused, it might be helpful for you to comment below the answer with a followup question.

Comment: Thank you for reading and helping me to solve this question. I believe this problem has been solved. xD xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition of the symmetric difference of $2$ sets
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \in A \Delta B &\iff& (x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B ) \text{ or } (x \notin A \text{ and } x \in B ) \\
&\iff& (x \in \overline A \text{ and } x \notin \overline B ) \text{ or } (x \notin  \overline A \text{ and } x \in \overline B ) \\
  &\iff& x \in \overline A \Delta  \overline B.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you Donald, you just helped my miserable life T_T I hope you are enjoying your day